# Doctrine exception - [Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, orm, mappingexception

Hi I'm new in symfony.

I'm trying to generate entities from an existing database with doctrine.
When I run this command:

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AppBundle xml
```

I get this exception :

> [Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]
>   Property "shop" in "Bug" was already declared, but it must be declared only once

I have tried to search other solutions, but I didn't find anythings.
How can I solve this problem?

This is how mysql workbench creates my table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `db`.`bug` (
`id_bug` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`bug_name` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
`comment` VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
`status` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`customer_id` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' NOT NULL,
`shop_id` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' NOT NULL,
`admin_id` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id_bug`),
 INDEX `fk_bug_customer1_idx1` (`customer_id` ASC),
 INDEX `fk_bug_shop1_idx` (`shop_id` ASC),
 INDEX `fk_bug_admin1_idx1` (`admin_id` ASC),
 CONSTRAINT `fk_bug_customer1`
 FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`)
 REFERENCES `db`.`customer` (`id`)
 ON DELETE NO ACTION
 ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
 CONSTRAINT `fk_bug_shop1`
 FOREIGN KEY (`shop_id`)
 REFERENCES `db`.`shop` (`id`)
 ON DELETE NO ACTION
 ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
 CONSTRAINT `fk_bug_admin1`
 FOREIGN KEY (`admin_id`)
 REFERENCES `db`.`admin` (`id`)
 ON DELETE NO ACTION
 ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
 ENGINE = InnoDB
 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;
```

I'm working in symfony 3.3, mysql and php7.

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the table structure of `bug`

Comment: This is how mysql workbench creeates my table and I don't now why docrtine encounters this problem @JasonRoman

Comment: Check at your XML definition for the Bug entity - it sounds like you've defined the property `shop` more than once. Post it here if you have any doubts

Comment: It doesn't generate metadata for entites

Answer (score 0):

There were two problem:

1. First of all there was a relaction duplicated on the same enitity
2. It was not the only problem. We noticed that in doctrine occours problems when there is a primary key that is also a foreign key, so we added a new field **id** for the primary key.